# How to filter the files/project view in Netbeans?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I know this is not programming related question so to speak, but since we are programmers and we might use Netbeans for PHP development.

I am wondering how can I get in Netbeans a selection from a list of files quickly. Suppose there are different folders for MVC pattern and I edit 1 section of it. I would like to see the 3 files that I work with only now.

Suppose I want to get files from all folders that ends in : "_suffix.php"

Can I do that somehow quickly?

Comment: I don't know any way to do exactly that, but you can always use the search tool inside the project or files window. You just have to start typing

Comment: By starting search by typing only filters one file. I need to have 3 files as result each that is in model, view, controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Navigate --> Go To File** which pops open a combobox dialog that searches through all open projects (preference on current one) and include paths, allowing for wildcards.

I've bound (Tools --> Options --> Keymap) it to an easy keyboard shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+E) and use it almost as much as CTR+TAB to switch around files.

Comment: That sounds promising, can I put the popup in docking window?

Comment: @Pentium10 not as far as I know. Just tried it. It looks like a native OS dialog not a dockable netbeans one. Still, I believe an easy keyboard shortcut will give much faster access to it.